# Calculate the distance between two adjacent cities

Tags: python

I am reading a CSV file which is in format `city1, city2, the distance between those two cities`

```
a,b,100
b,c,200
```

If I get arguments `a and c` from the command line then how to calculate the distance for `a and c`.

my approach is first to find the distance for the adjacent city and go on until we reach the desired city and returns the cumulative sum.

I am stuck on it, can you guys help me out.

Comment: Looks like a standard (A*) search algorithm. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: ohh, I didn't know about the A* algorithm, will try to solve that using A*, thanks @Caramiriel